# Set up Visual Studio command line build environment with python

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio

I want to set up Visual Studio command line build environment with python so that I can use

`subprocess.call(['msbuild', 'myapp.sln /p:Configuration=Release'])`

to build my project with automation.

I have some other dependencies need to use a portable scripting language, so I chose python.

Is there any ways to do so? Thanks in advance.

---

Trial 1 (failure):

I tried to call `vcvarsall.bat` in python. However, it seems that it did not actually setup the environment for me.

```
import os
import subprocess

# Backup current environment vars
envvar_backup_list = [
    'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH',
    'PATH'
]

envvar_backup_val_list = []

for i in envvar_backup_list:
    envvar_backup_val_list.append(os.environ.get(i, None))

# Set CMAKE environment vars
os.environ['CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH'] = 'C:\\Qt\\Qt5.3.1\\5.3\\msvc2013_64\\lib\\cmake\\'

# Set MSVC environment path
current_path = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\')
ret = subprocess.call(['vcvarsall.bat', 'amd64'], shell=True)
os.chdir(current_path)

subprocess.call(['msbuild'], shell=True)
subprocess.call(['cl.exe'], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The command line instance that `vcvarsall.bat` and other commands run are not the same since each time you call `subprocess.call()` a new process is spawned, so that first call probably is initializing the build environment but then being killed. What you need to do is something like,

```
build = subprocess.Popen(['vcvarsall.bat', 'x86', '&&', 'msbuild', myProject.sln, '/p:Configuration=Release'])
build.wait()

if build.returncode != 0:
    sys.exit("Build failed.")
```

PS: Reading `vcvarsall.bat` path from registry would be more portable, see the key `SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\<version>\\ShellFolder`.